# How to feed data into a polynomial basis function regression (unregularized) for degree n?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

We know that polynomial base function Models is:

$$t = \sum_{i=0}^n w^T\phi_j(x) = w_0*\phi_0(x) + w_1*\phi_1(x) + w_2*\phi_2(x)+ ....$$ 
$$\phi_j(x) = x^j$$

**Problem:** I am not sure how to pass the data to the model. For example, degree 2 polynomial base function regression is:
$$t  = w_0 + w_1*x +  w_2 * x^2  $$

Now I want to feed a table of data into Degree 2 model:

```
Employee    Target_income    factor_1  factor_2  factor_3  factor_4
A                 100           10        12        9          8
B                 150           19        17        15         10
C                 200           25        15        16         12
```

To find optimal $w^T$, we find the minimum of square error:
$$E(w) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^n \{ t_i - w^T\phi(x_i) \}^2$$
Okay, I know that $t_i =[100, 150,200]^T$. 
What is $w^T\phi(x_i)$ for each employee i here?

To be more precise, when i=1 how can I put the data into this model:
$$t_1 - w^T\phi(x_1) = $$
 $$t_1 - (w_0 + w_1*x_1 +  w_2 * x_1^2)$$
Employee A salary is defined by 4 factors (data points), but we only have 1 x.

Comment: I hope I explained my confusion clearly. I might understand some concept wrong, but I can not find it.

Comment: Do you want that the salary of each employee by represented by a quadratic function of each factor ? This would make a lot of terms (in particular if you use the cross terms). Feasible but you need many, many data for that.

Comment: Degree 2 is an example. No, cross terms.i gave this fake data table , so that I can see an example of using data points to build regression model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion in comments, what it *seems* is that you want tht, for each employee $i$, his/her salary $t_i$ be represented as
$$t_i=a+(b_1 f_{1i}+b_2f_{1i}^2)+(c_1 f_{2i}+c_2f_{2i}^2)+(d_1 f_{3i}+d_2f_{3i}^2)+(e_1 f_{4i}+e_2f_{4i}^2)$$ which makes a linear regression for eight variables $(f_{ki},f_{ki}^2)$  for $k=1,2,3,4$ and $i=1,2,\cdots,n$

So,nine parameters. Now, use matrix calculations to get the answer.

Comment: Why do we have two $ c_1, c_2 $terms, for $f_2i$ and $f_3i$?

Comment: @DiWang. Simple !!! Typo's. I fix it.

Comment: All make sense now!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Attached a MATHEMATICA script showing a possible formulation

`data = {{ 100, 10, 12, 9, 8}, {150, 19, 17, 15, 10}, {200, 25, 15, 16, 12}};
n = 3;
m = 4;
W = {w1, w2, w3};
phi[k_, x_] := x^(k - 1)
Phi[x_] := {phi[1, x], phi[2, x], phi[3, x]}
EE[j_] := Sum[(data[[k, j + 1]] - W.Phi[data[[k, 1]]])^2, {k, n}]
EE0 = Sum[EE[j], {j, m}]`

and the generated output

$$
{\small{
\text{EE0}=\left(12-w_1-200 w_2-200{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\left(15-w_1-200 w_2-200{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\left(16-w_1-200
w_2-200{}^{\wedge}2w_3\right){}^2+\left(25-w_1-200 w_2-200{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\\
\left(10-w_1-150 w_2-150{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\left(15-w_1-150 w_2-150{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\left(17-w_1-150 w_2-150{}^{\wedge}2
w_3\right){}^2+\left(19-w_1-150 w_2-150{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\\
\left(8-w_1-100 w_2-100{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\left(9-w_1-100 w_2-100{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\left(10-w_1-100 w_2-100{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2+\left(12-w_1-100
w_2-100{}^{\wedge}2 w_3\right){}^2}}
$$

follows the minimization-resolution process

`der = Grad[EE0, W];
equs = Thread[der == 0];
sol = Solve[equs, W]`

giving

`{{w1 -> -(25/2), w2 -> 119/400, w3 -> -(3/4000)}}`

Follows the obtained adjust.

$$
$$

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: May I suggest that you give the Mathematica syntax **without** using MathJax ? This would for sure be more convenient to any one willing to try it. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici As you suggest. You are welcome.